# Appending strings into an array in Parse

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I just learned how to store an array into a Parse Cloud using the example provided by the Parse Documentation:

```
gameScore.addUniqueObjectsFromArray(["flying", "kungfu"], forKey:"skills")
gameScore.saveInBackground()
```

Now, utilizing this logic, I want to append strings into the array. So this is what I wrote:

```
@IBAction func requestButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var prayerRequests = PFObject(className: "PrayerRequests")
    prayerRequests.addObject(["YOIDJFO"], forKey:"skills")
    prayerRequests.saveInBackground()
}
```

Now, after having executed the function `requestButtonPressed` three times, in parse this is happening:

[image: Parse Array]

However. I don't want that to happen when I execute the function `requestButtonPressed` three times. I want it to be something like this:

[image]

Anybody have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Every time you use this statement `var prayerRequests = PFObject(className: "PrayerRequests")` a new `PFObject` will be created. In order to update a object you need to query the object first and then update its field. In your case you should first get the array by querying for the object, modify / append data to the array and then update the object.

Comment: That was one solution that I was thinking of but then wouldn't that mean I would have to create a new object every time I want to modify the array? That would mean I would have many unnecessary objects? Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing addObject, do `insertObject:{yourObject} atIndexPath:{storingPosition} forKey:{@"youKey"}.`

And the the value you are adding is an array `["YOIDJFO"]` , object should be like `{"YOIDJFO"}`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Could you please translate the syntax into swift code? I tried it and I'm getting some syntax errors...